# trigger mouseover event after manipulate the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list and all elements could be **removed** by cliking on the 'x' link.
The 'x' element appear only when the mouse is over the element (opacity: 0 by default)

When clicking on x, the current element is removed and the next one is replacing the previous one. The problem is the 'x' link is still hidden (no over event is fired while I don't move the mouse).

Is it a trick to fix this problem ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are not moving your mouse after delete then you can trigger the mouseover of next element through jquery at the end of delete function.

```
//logic of delete ends here

$("#nexElem-id").trigger("mouseover");
```

Comment: you can also do $("#nexElem-id").show();  if you just want to show that element